# Testing Web Service Clients in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I went through scala-play official documentation for testing endpoints using Mokito.

```
"A photoService " must {
    "Return photos" in {
      Server.withRouter() {
        case GET(p"/nature/photos") => Action {
          Results.Ok.sendResource("photos.json")
        }
      } { port =>
        WsTestClient.withClient { client =>
          val result: VerifyResponse = Await.result(new PhotoService().getPhotos(photoType), Duration.Inf)
          val response = Await.result(photoService.get("nature").get(), Duration.Inf)
          println("*************************************************************************************************")
          println("Photo Response : " + (response.json \ "entry" \ "photos").as[String])
          println("*************************************************************************************************")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the code which I have written. I have a list of questions here.

1) As it uses mock server, Is there a need to keep out actual server in start state?

2) By default play application starts on 9000 port. But I am getting the following error :

```
- must Get Authorization code from MockSocialProvider  *** FAILED ***
[info]   org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:9077
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
[info]   at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:417)
[info]   at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:413)
[info]   at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:237)
[info]   at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
[info]   at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:237)
[info]   at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
[info]   at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
[info]   at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
[info]   at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
[info]   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
[info]   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
[info]   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
[info]   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
```

Here I have not started the server thinking how will it be possible to start play application in dev as well as test state?
How 9077 port is getting assigned to it?

Please help.

Comment: What version of play are you using. do you have the port set in your application.conf or something. Looks like play 2.5 start with a random port https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWebServiceClients.

Comment: @Stephen , I am currently using play 2.5
This code is written under Test folder. To get this code executed, do we need to start the play application?